# How to automate the testing of Outlook Add-In?

Tags: c#, testing, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Addin developed in C#,VSTO and has a lot of unstructured code and very huge in size. every time there is a modification / Update ,I have to Manually test it from end to end which is very painful and time consuming. This add in has a lot of rules whch pops up alert / dialog box and user has to take some actions on that.
Is there any way/tool which can be used to automate this task?

Answer (score 3):

I would work on adding unit tests to the existing code; with unit tests to check that everything still works after your changes you won't need to run your end-to-end tests so frequently.

You can also automate your end-to-end acceptance tests by using the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework to drive Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can also experiment with [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com)